# ¿Cómo puedo cambiar la posición del ícono alineado a la izquierda (android:drawableStart) en un TextInputEditText?

Tags: android

He logrado colocar un recurso drawable en un TextInputEditText, con el atributo android:drawableStart, les muestro el código completo del widget a continuación:

```
        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/tilComentReporte"
        app:errorTextColor="@color/colorRojo"
        app:errorEnabled="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
        android:maxLines="10"
        android:background="@drawable/edt_bg_selector_fafa_orange"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/etComentReporte"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:background="@null"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:lines="5"
            android:gravity="top|start"
            android:singleLine="false"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine|textAutoComplete"
            android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_contacto_nar"
            android:drawablePadding="15dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/lato"
            android:hint="@string/sign_describe_tu_problema"
            android:paddingStart="15dp"
            android:textSize="16sp" />
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Y se ve como en la imagen que muestro a continuación:

[image: Icono por default]

Pero en realidad busco que se vea así:

[image: Como debe verse el ícono]

Busqué atributos xml tanto en el TextInputLayout asi como en el TextInputEditText pero no encuentro ninguno que realice un cambio en la posición del ícono; también estuve buscando un rato en Internet y demás pero no encuentro tutorial, pregunta o solución aunque sea aproximada de que puedo realizar para lograr colocar en la parte superior izquierda mi ícono.

¿Alguna idea de como puedo realizarlo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Después de seguir buscando por Internet, logré encontrar una solución.
Primeramente en este [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33805452/how-to-get-edittextmultiline-leftdrawable-on-top-position) sugiere en la respuesta aceptada, que no es posible colocar el ícono en la parte superior, sin embargo, hay que envolver al EditText dentro de un LinearLayout y coloca el código de ejemplo. Yo tome esa idea, y lo logre a través de traslapar la imagen dentro del TextInputLayout con un FrameLayout envuelto en un LinearLayout. El código quedo de esta manera:

```
        <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <FrameLayout
            android:background="@drawable/edt_bg_selector_fafa_orange"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="start">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/tilComentReporte"
                android:gravity="top|start"
                app:errorTextColor="@color/colorRojo"
                app:errorEnabled="true"
                android:maxLines="10"
                android:background="@drawable/edt_bg_selector_fafa_orange"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                    android:id="@+id/etComentReporte"
                    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                    android:background="@null"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:lines="5"
                    android:gravity="top|start"
                    android:singleLine="false"
                    android:inputType="textMultiLine|textAutoComplete"
                    android:drawablePadding="15dp"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/lato"
                    android:hint="@string/sign_describe_tu_problema"
                    android:paddingStart="20dp"
                    android:textSize="16sp" />
            </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

            <ImageView
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:scaleType="fitStart"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_contacto_nar" />
        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Y la vista quedó de esta manera:

[image: Nueva vista]